# Java.util.timer - @Override with different parameters ( run() ) or workaround

Tags: java, timer, overriding, timertask

I've got a question about the java.util.timer.

I have a little application, which does use the timer to trigger an alarm.

The timer is set from the Buttonlistener:

```
if (timer1) {
      t1 = new Timer();
      t1.schedule(new AlarmTask(),(n_timer1.getInt()*60000),(n_timer1.getInt()*60000)+(n_delay1.getInt()*1000));
      ti1 = n_timer1.getInt()*60;     
      bt_timer1.setText("Stop");
      timer1 = false;
    }
    else {
      t1.cancel();
      timer1 = true;
      bt_timer1.setText("Start");
    }
```

and it's triggering the AlarmTask():

```
class AlarmTask extends TimerTask
  {
    @Override public void run()
    {
      try {
        File yourFile = new File("alarm.wav");
        AudioInputStream stream;
        AudioFormat format;
        DataLine.Info info;
        Clip clip;
        
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(yourFile);
        format = stream.getFormat();
        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
        
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I have different Actions which are starting the timer for this class.
Is there a way to hand over an parameter to the AarmTask()?
Or can you think of an workaround without adding multiple AlarmTask() classes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512157/how-to-pass-arguments-to-timertask-run-method

Comment: Thanks, I did search to much for add Parameters to Override so I overlooked this :I

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!