# How to extend method run in TimerTask . Must accept string parameter

Tags: java

I have this code

```
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    this.start.setBackground(Color.green);
    this.stop.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    if (!stopped) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    stopped = false;
    stato.setText("Avviato");
    timer = new Timer();
    if(giacRitardo>0)
        timer.schedule(S.run("argiacenze"), giacRitardo, giacRitardo);//parti dopo x secondi e itera ogni x secondi
    if(cliRitardo>0)
        timer.schedule(S.run("arclienti"), cliRitardo, cliRitardo);//parti dopo x secondi e itera ogni x secondi
```

// some other code

and

```
class TaskSchedulato extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        redirectSystemStreams();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        URL sito = null;
        try {
            sito = new URL(sUrl + "?aggiornamento=arlingue");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Indirizzo del sito mal formato o inesistente");
        }
        URLConnection yc = null;
        try {
            yc = sito.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Errore di connessione _ ");
        }
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskSchedulato.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String inputLine;
        try {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskSchedulato.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            dataErrore = new Date();
            System.out.println(sdf.format(dataErrore));
            System.out.println("Errore di connessione: " + dataErrore);
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskSchedulato.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
TaskSchedulato S = new TaskSchedulato();
```

I need to extend the method run above, so that i can pass a string parameter to it.
How can a do it.
I'm almost a newbye in java. So, please forgive me for the inexperience.

Actually I receive the error:
no suitable method found for run(String)
  method TimerTask.run() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method MainForm.TaskSchedulato.run() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass Arguments to Timertask Run Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512157/how-to-pass-arguments-to-timertask-run-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this way

```
class TaskSchedulato extends TimerTask {
    String stringa;
    public TaskSchedulato(String stringa){
        this.stringa=stringa;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
    //code here
    }
```

Thanks to @onurbaysan for the answer in the thread below
[How to Pass Arguments to Timertask Run Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512157/how-to-pass-arguments-to-timertask-run-method)

Answer (score 3):

**This can be easily achieved with [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).**

In short, method overloading is a language feature that allows to declare multiple methods with the same name, but different parameters.

Applied to your problem, instead of overriding the parent's `run()` method, just declare another `run()` method like this:

```
public void run(String someInput) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Of course, you can call `run()` from within `run(String)` if that makes sense in your program:

```
public void run(String someInput) {
    /* Do something with someInput */
    run(); // Hand over to parent's run() method
    /* Maybe do some other stuff */
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to use both, method overloading as well as overriding. Some more context would be required to give more specific advice.

Comment: Thank you domdom,

Comment: Thank you @domdom. I overloaded it. Now, when i call method as first parameter in timer.schedule, i receive a " 'void' type not allowed here" error.

Comment: Nicola, your `run()` method returns nothing (`void`). You are handing the return value of `run()` as first parameter to the `timer.schedule()` method. However, a method can not take a parameter of type `void`. What is the signature of `timer.schedule()`? What does it expect as first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

@domdom,
signature of timer.schedule is
    schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,long period)

I already used it in my working version of the program

```
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    this.start.setBackground(Color.green);
    this.stop.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    if (!stopped) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    stopped = false;
    stato.setText("Avviato");
    timer = new Timer();
    if(giacRitardo>0)
        timer.schedule(new TaskGiacenze(), giacRitardo, giacRitardo);
    if(cliRitardo>0)
        timer.schedule(new TaskClienti(), cliRitardo, cliRitardo);
    if(artRitardo>0)
        timer.schedule(new TaskArticoli(), artRitardo, artRitardo
    //..........
```

and

```
class TaskGiacenze extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        redirectSystemStreams();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        URL sito = null;
        try {
            sito = new URL(sUrl + "?aggiornamento=argiacenze");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Indirizzo del sito mal formato o inesistente");
        }
        URLConnection yc = null;
        try {
            yc = sito.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Errore di connessione _ ");
        }
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskGiacenze.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String inputLine;
        try {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskGiacenze.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            dataErrore = new Date();
            System.out.println(sdf.format(dataErrore));
            System.out.println("Errore di connessione: " + dataErrore);
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskGiacenze.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

but I had to create a class for each kind (one class for giacenze, another class for articoli etc.. etc...) instead of calling it as parameter.